# Android Studio Variables not appearing in OnClickListener body

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-debugging

I'm working in android studio using the debugger.

```
var loginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.loginButtonFinal)
var emailInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailInput)
var e = 2
loginButton.setOnClickListener {
    println("Log In Button pressed, will log in now")
    //            insert code for login in here
    //            signIn(email = emailInput.)
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the debugger at the line containing `var e = 2` I will see `loginButton` and `emailInput` output to the variable section of the debugger.  But if I place the debugger  inside of `loginButton.setOnClickListener`  they no longer appear.

I would like to be able to see variables after the click has occurred.  What can I do?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is an XY problem, because I don't see what use obsolete variables would be when debugging a click listener that cannot access them anyway.

Comment: You can write `val e = e` inside the `onClickListener` and you will see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the click listener, those variables are out of scope and the new scope of execution becomes the anonymous class.

If you would like to still inspect the views, then you should declare them as fields within the Activity class.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you really need, but you declare fields within the class, not a method `class MainActivity { var loginButton; var emailInput;  ...  }`